# When pressing q to exit git log, the log quits successfully, but the "q" also prints following the next prompt

Tags: git, git-bash

Reproduction:

```sh
$ git log
...           # <first section of log prints...>
:             # q pressed to exit
$ q           # q exits, but q is not eaten
```

Is this a configuration issue? I am using Git for Windows v2.27.0.

The problem does not occur in PowerShell/CMD, and also does not occur when using e.g. `less` on a large text file.

Comment: Does the issue persists with Git for Windows 2.28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has since been fixed. I'm not sure in which version, but `2.33.0.windows.2` does not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

That may be the case because you may have left the `git log` automatically so you don't have to press ":q" that was the case for me while I used the git bash on windows.
In case it was `cat` you wanted to exit press `ctrl + d`.

I hope this answers the question.